# Is '@' used in C++?

Tags: c++, keyword

Is '@' used in C++? In this [yacc file](http://www.computing.surrey.ac.uk/research/dsrg/fog/CxxTester.y) it is listed as a token. And i am sure i cant use @ as part of a variable name. Is @ used in C++? and how might i use it?

Comment: It's listed as a token but it isn't actually used anywhere in that grammar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it isn’t used in C++. It doesn’t appear anywhere in the standard. In particular, it does not appear in the set of legal C++ characters [lex.charset].

Comment: Some compilers use `@` though for identifier names after name mangling. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#How_different_compilers_mangle_the_same_functions for example.

Comment: @Johannes: true but this is strictly irrelevant for the C++ syntax and hence for a lexer spec. In the `yacc` file, the presence of the `@` symbol is a mistake. Furthermore, the symbol isn’t used anywhere else in the `yacc` file.

Comment: A source character doesn't have to be in the _basic_ source character set (so '@' isn't necessarily not allowed), but it must be handled as if it appeared as a \uXXXX universal character escape. So non-basic source characters can't appear in any identifiers or language tokens, but they could appear in character and string literals.

Comment: Sometimes '@' is used in the C++ literature to mean an arbitrary operator overload e.g. int operator@(bool x) const; And of course it is not meant to compile.

Answer (score 1):

As the above answers mentioned, '@' is not part standard C++; however, it does appear in Objective-C, and hence in Objective-C++, and hence, in real-world code, such as WebKit.